# Table cell being squashed by content in IE8

Tags: html, css

I have:

```
<table><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></table>
```

The td has a css width attribute setting it to 50px.

When content fills the other columns the the cell is squashed below 50px e.g. 32px.

How can I enforce the width with css ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the style `table-layout: fixed` on the `<table>` element.

Otherwise you get the `auto` table layout algorithm, which can be summarised as “let the browser guess, usually wrongly”.